# ionic5 set background color

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I have created a few custom colors and would like to set the background of a `ion-col` cell. But how? My colors work for buttons for instance:

```
<ion-button color="custom-blue" ... >...</ion-col>
```

but

```
<ion-col color="custom-blue" ... >...</ion-col>
```

fails. Same with `background-color`. Can I set `ion-col` colors at all or to I have to paste a `ion-item` into it?

Comment: try `--background: yourColorVariable;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color` CSS property. `color` attribute does not exist for `ion-col`

However, you won't be able to access your custom color directly inside SCSS file.
Use this to apply background to all `ion-col`:

```
ion-col{
background-color:var(--ion-color-custom-blue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add your *--ion-color-custom-blue* to varibles.scss

[image]

**In your html page**

```
<ion-col class="color-class">
```

**In your scss**

```
.color-class {
  background-color: var(--ion-color-custom-blue);
}
```